# Mac OS X Script to Install New Keyboard Layout

Tags: macos, keyboard

I would appreciate any help from Mac OS X developers. Is there a way to write some sort of script that can do at least steps 2-3 out of the following?

1. Download a custom keyboard layout
2. Move the keyboard layout to /System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/
3. Activate this keyboard layout as one of the System Input sources

I am asking at a very high-level -- what is the best scripting language to use, and are there any problems I may need to deal with? I don't mind, for example, skipping step #1 and packaging it with the script download itself.